# Weierstrass approximation theorem question $\lim_{x\to 1} (x-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^nf(x^n)=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

> I want to prove the following:
>   $$\lim_{x\to1} (x-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^nf(x^n)=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$$

I'm stuck however, because in other problems involving Weierstrass, I can solve them by proving them for $f(x)$ equal to a polynomial, but with this problem, I am stuck with this because of the $f(x^n)$ since I'm not sure how to plug in a polynomial and achieve this equality. I have only tried using Weierstrass, so maybe this technique doesn't work? Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $p(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}x^{k}$, then
\begin{align*}
&(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}p(x^{n})\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}x^{n}(x^{n})^{k}\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n(k+1)}\\
&=(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}\dfrac{1}{1-x^{k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{N}a_{k}\dfrac{1}{1+x+\cdots+x^{k}}\\
&\rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{N}\dfrac{a_{k}}{k+1}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}p(t)dt.
\end{align*}

For the approximation, note that for $0<x<1$, 
\begin{align*}
(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}|f(x^{n})-p(x^{n})|\leq(1-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\|f-p\|_{L^{\infty}}=\|f-p\|_{L^{\infty}}.
\end{align*}